# Installing Opencv with C++ without Visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv, installation

I want to use opencv with C++.
But i dont want to install **Visual studio**.
Is there any way i can do that ?

I could not find any proper installation guide for that .

Comment: [quote] Unless you like making your life complicated, the message is clear. Don't do it, install VS [unquote], cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15409908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is just an IDE that helps you to develop your project. To use OpenCV library on windows, you have to  add the IncludePath, LibraryPath, and link the ddl libs. In fact Visual Studio make all the stuff easier.

There might be another solution by [using MingGW compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7), but it is not recommended since you are using Windows and Visual Studio is the better choice.